# Remove ? with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a Wordpress installation that works and a htaccess-file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Outside Wordpress I have created links like this:**

http://www.test.com/butik/?my-url

I think it looks nice except for the "?". Is it simple to add something to my htaccess-file to remove it?

http://www.test.com/butik/my-url/ would be perfect. Does it matter if I run a file at the path http://www.test.com/butik/index.php? Would it collide?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) $1%1? [L]
```

So, given your example, `$1` would be `/butik/` and `%1` would be `my-url` (captured from the `RewriteCond`) Also, the first `RewriteCond` should prevent any conflicts with index.php requests.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not get it to work. Instead I got the message "File not found".

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add the `[R]` to the rule, change the last line to `RewriteRule (.*) $1%1? [L,R]`.  That will remove the `?` and then on redirect, your other rule will direct it to the `index.php` file.  That seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: What it should do is redirect from /butik/?my_post to /butik/my_post. That part seems to work. It should also load the data from index.php in /butik/ (which it does when /butik/?my_post). That part don't work.